# When I code ` torch.addmm` in pytorch and then Segmentation fault, why?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

- The version of python is 3.6.0
- The version of pytorch is 0.4.1

When I do some coding below, the error happens and the programme exit completely. Why? How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: could not reproduce. python 3.6.5 pytorch 0.4.1

Comment: Neither is it reproducible in Python 3.6.6 and PyTorch 1.0.0

Comment: It is good practice to share your environment details(OS, CUDA etc)? And, have you tried running same code from command line?